# ASP.NET MVC 2: Nested folder structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the follow folder strucutre as default when creating a MVC project in Visual Studio:

```
.
├── content 
├── controllers
│   └── home
├── models 
└── views
    ├── account
    └── home
        └── index.aspx
```

I want to create a similar structure but WITHIN an admin folder like so:

```
admin
├── content 
├── controllers
│   └── home
│       └── controller
├── models 
└── views
    ├── account
    └── home
        └── index.aspx
```

When I try to link to /admin/home it says it can't be find. Is this method of nesting even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is an "Area", just right click your project and select add -> Area and name it admin.
That will create following structure:

```
Areas
->admin
 ->controllers 
 ->models
 ->views
```

You might also want to checkout these sites:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx
  (or if you like  [videos](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2-areas/) more)
- http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-areas/

both should offer a good overview of the areas concept.

Comment: the server still can't find the folders in the area?

Comment: :) and you have to specify the routes specific to that area in *AreaRegistration.cs, and there should be a default route in there.